# Why no python implicit line continuation on 'and', 'or', etc.?

Tags: python

Is there a reason why this doesn't work in Python?

```
if 1 != 1 or
   2 != 2:
   print 'Something is wrong...'
```

Comment: Perhaps they just didn't feel it was worth implementing.

Comment: The answer is _right in your question_. `import this` and read it for the word `implicit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this prevents a grammar ambiguity, but I feel that this behaviour is in the spirit of [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), specifically 'Simple is better than complex' (among others). In other words, 'Unless you have a good reason, why should expressions span multiple lines?'. If you have a good reason, the syntax devices to get around this are provided.

[edit]
I did some more reading, and there are a few references of interest:

- The lexical definition of statements says that logical lines end in with a [newline](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#logical-lines). Each case for adding an implicit continuation becomes and exceptional case.
- [PEP 3125](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3125) for Python 3, proposed removing slash (`\`) continuation, but was rejected due to lack of support.

  - [Discussion](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-May/007244.html) in the mailing list reminds us that parenthetical continuation occurs because newlines do not end statements while parenthesis remain unbalanced.
  - In that same thread, Guido opposes the change because errors like the following are disguised:

---

```
    x = y+    # Used to be y+1, the 1 got dropped
    f(x)
```

My final point is, the slash acts (or open parens) acts as a reminder that the statement is continued on the next line. Depending on your indentation, it's possible that the continuation could be mistaken for a separate statement (which I think this other [response](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/007063.html) touches on).

Comment: Other than anecdotes about python 'discouraging' this behaviour, I found some functional reasons why this is the case.

Comment: Ahhhh the `y+` example is great, that makes a lot of sense; thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Implicit line continuation only happens in Python if parentheses, brackets, or braces are open. Put parentheses around your condition and it will work.

Comment: But _why_ have they chosen not to do implicit line continuation for `and` and `or` without parenthesis? Is there an ambiguity I don't see in doing so?

Comment: @kindall: I'd hate to say it, but you completely missed the point of my question. I was asking for the **reason**, not the fix.

Answer (score 4):

Because "explicit is better than implicit"; an un-marked line continuation throws off the reader of the code (especially in a language with syntactically significant whitespace), and code is read much more often than it is written.

Comment: This is the actual reason why. With a `\\` or a matched pair likes braces, brackets, or parenthesis, it's explicit that the line is not finished.

Comment: I think that this is what it comes down to and other continuation types don't have so much potential for problems.